# How to execute .PS1 file from Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017

I have a .PS1 file as part of Visual Studio 2017 project. Let me know, how to execute this script file in debug mode (VS debug mode)? also let me know, how to pass input variables to this script file?

Comment: Its an opinion based question which doesn't fit in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/wiki/Installing-PowerShell-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2017) and the [PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0).